# Check difference between two array without any function

Tags: php, arrays, php-7

```
$array1=[1,2,3,4,5,6];
$array2=[1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10];
```

I want the difference between these two array without using any function like array_diff or etc

Comment: Dont use function. You can write your own custom code.

Comment: can you please tell me  ?

Comment: What output you need? What difference you wanna see?

Comment: Can you implement your own array_diff or non-function use at all? (it does nopt make sense...)

Comment: I want to  show 
[7,8,9,10]
because its not exist in $array1;

Comment: Can you use `in_array`?

Comment: dwinder someone ask me in an interview to show difference between 2 array without using any function

Comment: no i cant use any function like in_array,array_diff,array_intersect etc

Comment: `isset` is fine?

Comment: @MuhammadSaad check my solution, if you don't want to use `in_array`, write a custom implementation for that too

Comment: i think yes its fine

Answer (score 1):

Obviously I'm not gonna answer this homework/interview task with a code dump, but with the general (and tedious) approach:

- [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) over both lists (`$array1 as $x1` / `$array2 as $x2`).
- Keep a state flag `$found = false;`
- If the inner foreach finds `$x1 == $x2`, then set `$found`
- And after the inner loop, collect `$x1` in a difference list (`if (!$found)`).

Answer (score 0):

```
   $diffArray=array();

   foreach($array1 as $value){ 
      if(!in_array($value,$array2)
         $diffArray[$value] = $value;
    }

   foreach($array2 as $value){ 
      if(!in_array($value,$array1)
         $diffArray[$value] = $value;
    }
```

Iterate over the arrays separately one by one, put the difference in array KEY as well to avoid repetition. In first loop, it will select the elements that are in array1 but not in array2 and in second loop it's vice versa.

Comment: You are using `in_array` which is not allowed... (according to OP demands)

Comment: I guess he just meant `array_diff`, he can write custom implementation of `in_array` as well\